# Do levels make a hidden difference to damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've heard that being below the level of one's enemies causes damage reduction, like how being above the level of one's enemies causes XP reduction. Is it true that there's hidden damage reduction based on how far one's level is below the enemy's? If so, what is that formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is, [there is a damage multiplier that is applied to your character when you are facing an enemy](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Damage#Borderlands_2). If the enemy level is  :

- **strictly less than 3 level(s) above you** :  the damage multiplier is **1** (nothing changes)
- **3 or more levels above you**  : the damage multiplier is **0.88^level difference**. Which mean *the higher the level difference, the smaller the damage multiplier (and so the less damage you deal)*.

Comment: Sauce?987654321

Comment: Added wikia source.